# Как не прервать аудио-стрим с сайта при переходах между страницами?

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, аудио, web-audio

Необходимо добавить на сайт прослушивание аудио-композиций, которое не будет обрываться при переходе между страницами.

Сайт работает под `Yii2`.

Первое, что приходит в голову - весь сайт сделать на `ajax`, в том числе переходы между страницами, но это переделывание работающего функционала. Прошу совета, существуют ли другой подход и решения?

Comment: Если коротко, то никак. По крайней мере без SPA (AJAX, PJAX).

Comment: Ну почему же `никак` :)  `Frames` еще вроде в спецификацию `html` входят :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте в качестве главной страницу с таким упрощённым содержимым:

```js
document.onclick = function(){document.querySelector("audio").play()}; // запускаем фоновую музыку кликом по произвольному месту в документе
```

```html
<audio src="sound.mp3"></audio>
<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com" width=100% height=100%></iframe>
```

где [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) - собственно сайт. Способ хорош тем, что одинаково подходят свой или чужой сайт.