# Музыка без обрывов на сайте при переходе между страницами "wordpress"

Tags: wordpress, аудио, wordpress-плагины, mp3, плеер

Музыка без обрывов на сайте при переходе между страницами "wordpress"
Хочу сделать аудио плеер который можно запустить и переходить по страницам, а аудио продолжало играть
Сейчас установил плагин WavePlayer, но в нем нет такой функции(

Comment: что-то я сомневаюсь что это на wordpress и такого же уровня CMS доступно.... потому как при любом переходе между страницами там идете перезагрузка страницы, перезапуск скриптов....
разве что сохранять текущую позицию этого плеер и при запуске проверять, есть ли такие данные и продолжать с этого же момента. но тогда это будет выглядеть как заикание....

Comment: @Softovick что бы не сомневаться надо  учить технологии. От движка это не зависит ВОООБЩЕ.

Comment: Есть [способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141589/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8/1228883#1228883)

Comment: Подобная функция в аудио-плагинах WordPress платная. Вот один из лучших плагинов - https://sonaar.io/free-mp3-music-player-plugin-for-wordpress/

Comment: жаль что бесплатных плагинов нет(